one slide poking out from left at last 3 slides
hey its my first time posting on stack overflow



.recommend {
  height: 220px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: rgb(237, 235, 233);
  line-height: 24px;
  margin-bottom: 40px;
  margin-top: 24px;
  padding-bottom: 64px;
  padding-top: 32px;
  }
  .recommend .swiper{
    width: 1140px;
    padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;;
     overflow: hidden;
  }
.recommend  .swiper-slide {
        background-color: white;
        height: 126px;
        
        width: 313px !important;
        border-radius: 8px;
        padding-bottom: 16px;
        padding-left: 24px;
        padding-right: 24px;
        padding-top: 16px;
        flex-direction: column;
        margin: 15px;
        margin-right: 0px;
}
<section class="recommend">
    <div class="swiper mySwiper3">
        <div class="swiper-wrapper">

        
          <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 2</div>
          <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 3</div>
          <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 4</div>
          <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 5</div>
        </div>

</section>



i tried to use padding to remove the poking slide but its box shadow stil lingers. i used swiper js by the way

Please also provide the html, also preferably using a snippet so that we can reproduce the issue.

Not sure if it'll work but try adding "display: flex" to .recommend  and "flex-basis: 33%" instead of "width: 313px !important;" to .swiper-slide

nope it just pushes it in even further

Ok, I added a snippet to your question in order to run the code here, maybe update it to render the same thing as your image.

increasing the width from 1140px to 1150px and using padding-right:15px !important  fixed the problem lol

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
